# Animating multiple SVG paths

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to learn the specifics of animating SVG paths and there is one issue that is confusing to me.

[This great example by Max](https://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/xxrGdR?editors=1100) on Codepen is what I am trying to accomplish. Animating a single path makes sense to me but what about multiple paths of varying lengths (as in the example)?

Each stroke length is different, right?

Why then, for example, does a **stroke-dasharray** of **680** within the path with ID **structure** work?

```
&#structure {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-dasharray: 680;
      stroke-dashoffset: 680;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
    }
```

Shouldn't some of these paths not render fully if they are shorter than 680? Are all of these path's lengths 680? They don't look the same length. What am I missing/not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

It works because none of the paths are *longer* than 680.  If they were longer than 680 the solid part of the dash pattern wouldn't reach the full length of the path.

A dash pattern of "680" is a shortcut for "680 680". Which descibes a pattern of 680 solid dash followed 680 gap, then repeats.

The paths start out with a dash-offset of 680, meaning that they are first rendered within the 680 gap of the dash pattern.  Then in the animation, the dash offset is slowly reduced to 0.  Simulating the drawing of the line.

If a line is shorter than 680, all that will happen is that there will be a period in the animation where some of the gap is animated in, before the solid part of the dash becomes visible.  The effect of this is just that the shorter the line, the later it will appear to start drawing.  You can see this happening with the lines in the interior of the XBox image.

Comment: Thanks Paul! After reading your answer and playing around with the dasharray / dashoffset I see exactly what you mean.